# MVC Model Validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I have a View binded to a ViewModel with DataAnnotations for validation and i have an Action with Model input parameter (for ModelBinding). My code looks like...

```
public ActionResult MyMethod (MyModelDefinition model, string ddlValue){
    if (ModelState.IsValid) { return RedirectToAction ("...");}

    // If my model is not valid i want to change it and return the View Again...
    model.field1 = "xpto";

    return View(model);
}
```

When i do this i have validation errors (even in my field1 witch is a required one and i fill it before my View was rendered).

What i'm missing?

Thank U All..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the value from the model state if you intend to modify it in the controller or when you render the view the HTML helper that you have used to render this value will first look in the POSTed values and after that in the model. That's the expected behavior.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyMethod(MyModelDefinition model, string ddlValue)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid) 
    { 
        return RedirectToAction ("...");
    }

    // Remove field1 from ModelState if you intend to 
    // modify it in the controller
    ModelState.Remove("field1");
    model.field1 = "xpto";
    return View(model);
}
```